# List of file share for all storage accounts in Azure

Tags: azure

I'd like to gather a list of all of the File Shares under every storage account we have in Azure.  Most of the scripts i'm seeing show how to gather the file shares for an individual storage account.  Is there a way to gather the info for all of them at once?

Comment: Can you share what you have so far? Maybe the ensemble of all those scripts you already saw?

Comment: I was looking at the Get-AzureStorageShare command but was having a hard time figure out how to do it on all of the storage accounts at once.

Comment: Any updates for your question? Does my answer solve it for you? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick bash script and one-liner using azure-cli 2.0.79 that might help you get started with iterating over all storage accounts under a single subscription.

From a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#get a list of storage accounts
 for account in `az storage account list --query '[].{Name:name}' --output tsv` 
#iterate over storage accounts
 do 
  echo $account $(az storage share list --account-name $account --output tsv | awk '{print $2}')
done
```

One liner:

```
for account in `az storage account list --query '[].{Name:name}' --output tsv`;  do echo $account $(az storage share list --account-name $account --output tsv | awk '{print $2}') ; done
```

This should output:

```
storageaccountname1 <share1> <share2> <share3>
storageaccountname2 <share1> <share2>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Here is my output. Am I typing something wrong?

At line:2 char:5
+  for account in `az storage account list --query '[].{Name:name}' --o ...
+     ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:4 char:4
+  do echo $account $(az storage share list --account-name $account --o ...
+    ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: Check the update. You will need to put `;` between the commands if doing it on the cli and not in a `./<script>`

Comment: Thanks.  When I use the one liner I get...  At line:1 char:4
+ for account in `az storage account list --query '[].{Name:name}' --ou ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: You seem to be running it from PowerShell. I get that error when I run the command from the PowerShell shell. Select bash shell from the Azure Portal.

Comment: Powershell.  I installed the Azure CLI module.  Should I just use command prompt?

Comment: This is a bash script. You can run this from the portal by selecting bash as the shell where the drop down option to select the CLI `powershell V` is. Let me see what I can do with a powershell port of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell script to output much the same as the bash script. The bash script uses a *for* loop in bash shell with the azure-cli. This one uses *foreach* loop in powershell with the azure-cli. Native powershell with the AZ commandlets doesn't seem to provide an easy way to do this (that I am aware of). Essentially both of these are using two tools to get the job done i.e. 1) Powershell or bash as the shell to loop and 2) azure-cli as the query method.

```
#Get storageaccount names
    $SAname=Get-AzStorageAccount

#Now iterate over the storageaccounts
    foreach ( $storageaccount in $SAname.StorageAccountName) 
    { write-output $storageaccount $(az storage share list --account-name $storageaccount --output tsv).replace("None","")}
```

It isn't pretty but it should give you an idea where to start.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I'm getting this error repeatedly.    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\temp\storage.ps1:6 char:38
+ ... geaccount $(az storage share list --account-name $storageaccount --ou ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Have you tried running it from Powershell shell in the Azure portal? You'll be able to redirect it to a file in blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Azure File Share through PowerShell, you'd better use the [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-3.3.0) instead of the Azure CLI, I think the CLI is not suitable for Linux. You can install the Azure PowerShell module and then use the script like this:

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount
foreach ($storage in $storageAccount) { 
    if($storage.PrimaryEndpoints.File -ne $null){
        Get-AzRmStorageShare -ResourceGroupName $storage.ResourceGroupName 
        }
}
```

Comment: I use the az cli all the time. The new interactive mode is pretty cool `az interactive`. Your script: On macOS pwsh and the cloud shell PS that prompts for the storageaccountname  `cmdlet Get-AzRmStorageShare at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
StorageAccountName:`